# Is the following sentence grammatically and meaningfully correct ?

Tags: anglais, apprentissage

I'm learning French from [Alice Ayel's video series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EijavsrgOrc&index=7&list=PLD0666ZhOzwhyOzXQN7lxY8-K_UIRakJL&frags=pl%2Cwn), and as an exercise to the last lecture that I watch, I want to say that

> Me too when I went to İzmir, which is a city in Turkey.

I wrote

> Moi aussi alors que Je allé a İzmir, qui est une ville dans Torque.

However, when I translate it in google translate, it gives a weird output in Turkish, but exactly the same sentence I gave above when I translate it in English, so my question is that is the sentence grammatical & meaningfully correct ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few things to change:

1. Your verb is in the passé composé, which is good. However, this tense requires an auxiliary. In the case of *aller*, the auxiliary is *être*. Conjugate *être* for *je* in the present, and you get *suis*.

   > Moi aussi alors que je **suis** allé à İzmir

   Why? Because French makes heavy use of **compound tenses** (*temps composés*). Many of the times and aspects we want to express are not possible or not common with simple tenses consisting of one verb. The compound tenses use one or more auxiliary (*être*, *avoir*) and/or modal (*aller*) verbs to yield the complete meaning. But you still translate such phrases as one word in English (*suis allé* ~ *went*), and especially in Turkish, where verbs are [affixed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_grammar#Compound_bases) instead.

   For more, read about [isolating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolating_language) (Mandarin), [fusional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusional_language) (French) and [agglutinative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agglutination) (Turkish).

---

2. The French name for the country is not Torque, but [*la Turquie*](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/Turkey). Also, the preposition for feminine countries is usually *en* (often directional) or *de* (often possessive). Here, jlliagre suggests *de*.

   > Moi aussi alors que je suis allé à İzmir, qui est une ville **de Turquie**.

---

3. Instead of *alors que*, you can use *quand*. Although "when" is one of the senses of *alors que*, according to jlliagre it more often means "despite" (or I might read "whereas").

   > Moi aussi **quand** je suis allé à İzmir, qui est une ville de Turquie.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Luke. I used "dans" as preposition "to".

Comment: Also, since the first sentence has a verb, 'alle ', why do we need a "to be" ver there ?

Comment: Because that's how the *passé composé* [works](https://frenchtogether.com/passe-compose/)

Comment: Plutôt : *Moi aussi quand je suis allé à İzmir qui est une ville de Turquie.*

Comment: @onurcanbektas Expanded and corrected the answer.

Comment: @jlliagre Fixed *de*. Do you agree with my reading of *quand* here or is this a context where *alors que* is impossible? (And can you identify why?)

Comment: Nowadays, *alors que* is much more likely to mean *Mee too despite the fact I went to Izmir*.

Comment: Voir aussi https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/juridi/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_p&page=9BM1iKrqzOKc.html

Comment: On pourrait aussi encore améliorer la phrase en supprimant *qui est* qui est inutile:  *Moi aussi quand je suis allé à İzmir, une ville de Turquie.*